# Will VMWare Workstation 14 or 15 run with i5-2400 Intel processor or not?

Tags: cpu, vmware, vmware-workstation

I have heard various stories either way - some people say yes, some say no, and if they say yes, they said they have had "problems" installing or using it - without clarification.

So the question is: Will VMWare Workstation 14 or 15 run with i5-2400 Intel processor or not ?  That's a Sandy Bridge architecture.

Intel's site for the processor says it supports VT-X but as I said some people say they have experienced "issues".

Thank you.

Comment: Have you downloaded the free version and tried it?  Are you experiencing issues?  What problems or issues are you referring to?

Comment: I am using Workstation Pro 12 and experiencing no problems.

I am worried that upgrading to 14/15 will cause issues as I have a fairly old CPU - Sandy Bridge.

I havent tried 14/15 yet - is it worth it to even upgrade ?  Is there anything worth upgrading for ?